# Two softwares accessing the same memory address

Tags: memory, memory-management

What happens if one software goes to the address 0x1500 and sets the value 6 there, and then another software goes to the same address and reads it, Will read 6? Will it always be like that? What are the mechanisms at the OS level and at the Processor level that are in charge of that?

Comment: In modern OS's - access violation - processes cannot access the same memory (unless that's explicitly set up for a particular block of memory)

Comment: @Blorgbeard Due to virtual memory, if both programs allocated space at the address 0x1500, they can write and read different addresses to their respective 0x1500s, which are actually 'virtually' mapped to pages which the OS is allowed to place anywhere it likes (RAM, hard disk...), and the program only thinks it is at 0x1500.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Correction... Processes CAN access the same memory IF the coder knows how to do it. I don't know this myself but I DO know of someone who did this on Windows XP

Comment: @Patashu yeah, I was disregarding virtual memory since OP evidently didn't know about it, and assuming he meant the same real address.

Answer (score 2):

Well it depends...

it depends on

1. Processor (8051/x86/x386...)
2. Processor mode (real/protected)
3. Operating System (supports protected mode?)
4. Process mode (user mode/kernel mode)
5. Address type (shared/private)
6. Address access privileges (allowed/denied)

now here are some combinations and their outcomes

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
PROCESSOR MODE     PROCESS MODE    ADDRESS TYPE    PRIVILEGE   OUTCOME
======================================================================
   Real                Kernel          --             --        r/w
   Protected           Kernel        shared           ok        r/w
   Protected           user          shared           ok        r/w
   Protected           user          private          --        r/w with diff result
   Protected           Kernel        shared           no        error
   Protected           user          shared           no        error
     ....
======================================================================
```

NOTE: in real mode you can always talk with each other. In protected mode it depends. some (old) processors dont support protected mode (8051/8086 etc.) some new processor may be in one of the two modes - either real or protected. in protected mode, you can talk if the OS allows. if not, you get error. the protected mode could be paged or non-paged. paged mode supports private addresses (with same value), non-paged mode does not. two diff. process can read/write same location in their private address yet they can get diff. values.

as you can see, it is really complicated.

**Also,**
Normal *software* work in protected + usermode + private memory. hence two diff software can both perform r/w at address 0x1500 and yet both will have independent values. what that software wrote is what it will read.

Comment: What if the machine is windows 7 32bit?

Comment: Win 7 = protected. 32bit has no meaning in current context. *normal* software would be running in user-mode. if it accesses private memory then it has own private copy of the location. if it accesses shared memory then depending on privileges either it will get the data or cause error. *ab-normal* softwares are like device-drivers. they run in kernel-mode. they can access both private and shared memory. in addition they can also access private-to-other-process memory. A rouge device driver can screw things.

Answer (score 1):

This used to be possible by default in early operating systems, such as Windows 95. This was very problematic.

Chips Challenge was a game for Windows 95 that had a bug in it - if you simultaneously collected a key and died on the same tile/step, its logic would go wrong and it would write to the wrong spot in memory. Since every program shared the same memory space, it could now be writing to memory that another program was using - causing other programs to crash and possibly making the operating system unstable and requiring a reboot.

In modern operating systems, each program now has its own virtual memory space - what each program thinks the memory is laid out as, is actually a fiction generated by the CPU and OS together, such that all memory reads and writes, if they are done out of bounds, are intercepted and prevented, and the real places in memory that the program is writing and reading to are unknown to the program (which also allows memory to be 'paged' out from RAM onto the hard disk, and paged back in in a different place when it is next detected to be needed).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging

Comment: It is possible, on modern operating systems, to write to the address space of other processes. You just need the appropriate permissions.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Yes, but it won't be something as simple as 'writing to the same 0x1500'. You are still working within the model of virtual memory. (That said, if you know of the steps required to do this, feel free to write about it, I am curious myself)

Comment: Windows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674(v=vs.85).aspx